# PrintDialog.ShowDialog() causes visual styles on all controls to become disabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, printing

I'm using Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2012. Showing a print dialog causes all controls throughout all forms in the application to lose their visual styles. By this I mean the buttons lose their rounded edges and become rectangles like in Windows XP. The checkboxes also lose their visual styles upon hovering over them after showing the print dialog.

The following line of code causes the problem:

```
pdlg.ShowDialog();
```

pdlg is a PrintDialog. This only happens in one project; other projects that use the same line of code work correctly. The PrintDialog does not even have to be connected to a PrintDocument for the issue to occur (no BeginPrint/PrintPage event needs to fire). There are no errors thrown. I'm not saving any preferences to disk in the application.

I have tried:

- Cleaning/rebuilding the solution
- Deleting and recreating the PrintDocument control and PrintDialog control
- Restarting the computer
- Converting to different .NET Framework versions
- Running the application on the same machine as a different user - **visual styles stay enabled correctly**
- Running the application on a different machine - **visual styles stay enabled correctly**
- Emptying the user's Temp directory
- Renaming the assembly
- Moving the application to a different directory

My guess is that some file or registry setting is being saved internally somehow by .NET and it only applies to one application/user. Or some cache or something has become corrupt. I've run out of simple troubleshooting ideas. Has anyone seen this before? What should I try next?

Comment: The actual dialog displayed by PrintDialog comes from the printer driver.  Which has a knack for making a mess, even once reputable companies like HP write pretty shoddy drivers these days.  Look for a driver update or ditch the printer.

Comment: Thanks Hans! I tried switching the default printer to a different one and the problem went away! Looks like this Konica Minolta printer driver is to blame. It's already the latest version (from 2010)... I don't suppose there's anything that I can do to sandbox that call so it doesn't affect my application, is there?